# Should association method call counterpart's association method?

Tags: c++

Is it correct to call the method that associates the other object from the association method, or should we call both methods to associate them from outside these functions? Thank you.

```
#include <set>

class B;

class A {
public:
    void associate(B &b) {
         b_.insert(&b);
         b.associate(*this);
    }

private:
    std::set<B*> b_;
};

class A {
public:
    void associate(A &a) {
         a_.insert(&a);
         a.associate(*this);
    }

private:
    std::set<A*> a_;
};
```

Comment: Calling the method unconditionally will lead to an infinite recursion. Not calling it will make the class easy to misuse. I suggest coming up with some other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply check whether it is already associated, and if not, do it?

```
void A::associate(B &b) {
     if(not b_.contains(&b)) {
          b_.insert(&b);
          b.associate(*this);
     }
}
```

Goal should be to design your code robust. This way, you can call `associate` as often as you want and it will work just fine.